# Search Outlook inbox with Apple mail

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

My university prevents me from adding my email to the Apple mail app, meaning I can only receive emails through Outlook. This is pretty inconvenient when I'm searching for a specific email, since my email accounts are spread across the Apple mail and Outlook apps.

Is there a way I can search my Outlook inbox through the Apple mail app, or a way I can forward my emails from one app to the other?

Comment: You can certainly create a rule in Outlook to forward all mail to another email account, unless your organization has a rule against that sort of thing.

Comment: Is there documentation which _specifies_ a restriction on Apple Mail for your organization's email access, or you just haven't been able to get it to work?